# How to pass parameters from the Gruntfile.js to the webdriverio spec?

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, webdriver-io

I would like to parameterize my webdriverio specs from the Gruntfile.js.
The goal is to specify the host, the port, a username a password and maybe other parameters in Grunt and read them from the spec file.

Reading the Source Labs example from https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-webdriver#overview I set the host and the port in the options. But when configuring the port I got the following error:

```
/Users/sandro/Developing/Projekte/sling/svn/contrib/explorers/resourceeditor/frontend/node_modules/grunt-webdriver/node_modules/webdriverio/lib/utils/PromiseHandler.js:154
             throw error;
                   RuntimeError: RuntimeError
```

This is why I think there must be an other way to do that.
My Gruntfile.js looks like that:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {

var e2eTestSpecFolder = '../src/test/javascript/e2e/spec/**/*spec.js';

grunt.initConfig({
...
    webdriver: {
        options: {
            host: 'localhost',
            port: 8080
        },
        chrome: {
            tests: [e2eTestSpecFolder],
            options: {
                // overwrite default settings 
                desiredCapabilities: {
                    browserName: 'chrome'
                }
            }
        },
        firefox: {
            tests: [e2eTestSpecFolder],
            options: {
                // overwrite default settings 
                desiredCapabilities: {
                    browserName: 'firefox'
                }
            }
        }
    }
})

...
grunt.registerTask('desktop_build', ['webdriver:chrome', 'webdriver:firefox']);
};
```

Thanks in advance for any hints!

Update:
I use the following versions:

- grunt-cli: v0.1.13
- grunt: v0.4.5
- webdriver-manager: 3.0.0
- grunt-webdriver: 0.4.8

Comment: Hi. What is yr grunt and w.io  versions? What are you trying to achieve? To connect webdriver.io to an external hub/via proxy?

Comment: The test should open a website using a host and port and also login to this website using a username and a password. There the test creates data, deletes data and so on. But the host, port, username and password should be configurable. I would like to provide an initial configuration for these values in the grunt.js file and I would like to make them overridable from the command line.
But the question is, how to pass these variables from the grunt file to the webdriver.io spec.
Versions:
grunt-cli: v0.1.13
grunt: v0.4.5
webdriver-manager: 3.0.0
grunt-webdriver: 0.4.8

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I got your problem :)

These "host" and "port" parameters are the the pre-defined one and are using for another purpose (it's host and port where the tests will be executed, and you are redefining port - that's why they are failing, for example here - https://github.com/webdriverio/webdriverio/blob/master/examples/webdriverio.saucelabs.js you can see they are using for connecting to saucelabs). For that purposes the simpliest solution is defining ENV variables and make some default values for them (but you shouldn't do it inside gruntfile in fact, it's not neccessary)
You can define it in the file, where you are placing these variables for the first time, like:

```
testHost: (typeof(process.env.TEST_HOST) === 'undefined') ? 'http://localhost' : process.env.TEST_HOST;
```

And after that you are just providing TEST_HOST if it's needed as an env variable:

```
    Linux: sh~ TEST_HOST=http://google.com
grunt task
    Win: export TEST_HOST=http://google.com
grunt task
```

If you will not set the variable, then "http://localhost" will be the default one.

Comment: Ok, then I provide 'testHost' to the Gruntfile.js. The question is, how do I access that in the webdriverio spec?

Comment: @Sandro either with process.env.TEST_HOST, either with grunt.config.get()

Comment: I would prefer to use http://gruntjs.com/api/grunt.option for the testHost and not an ENV variable if that is possible. As this seems to be the way to define parameter in Grunt. But of course if that is not possible then I have to use the ENV variable.

Comment: I tried to log the `testHost` variable in the spec file with `console.log("process.env.testHost: "+process.env.testHost);` But that didn't seem to log the variable of the calling grunt configuration.

Comment: how do you run it? what is the output of `env | grep testHost` ?

Comment: I run the spec file with grunt-webdriver see
https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-webdriver

Comment: It works now by setting an env variable in the gruntfile with the `grunt-env` npm package (https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-env) and by reading process.env.ENV_VARIABLE in the spec file. But I would like a solution with gruntjs.com/api/grunt.option more if there is one.